# Correct usage of keras SpatialDropout2D inside TimeDistributed layer - CNN LSTM network

Tags: tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network, lstm, dropout

I have a burning issue on applying same dropout mask for all of the timesteps within a time series sample so that LSTM layer sees same inputs in one forward pass. I read multiple articles but did not find a solution to this. Does the following [implementation](https://raphaellederman.github.io/articles/videoclassification_2/#building-an-appropriate-classification-model) support this? Or this randomly drops different feature maps in each timestep?

```
dim = (420,48,48,1) # grayscale images of size 48x48
inputShape = (dim)
Input_words = Input(shape=inputShape, name='input_vid')
x = TimeDistributed(Conv2D(filters=50, kernel_size=(8,8), padding='same', activation='relu'))(Input_words)
x = TimeDistributed(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))(x)
x = TimeDistributed(SpatialDropout2D(0.2))(x)
x = TimeDistributed(BatchNormalization())(x)
x = TimeDistributed(Flatten())(x)
x = LSTM(200, dropout=0.2, recurrent_dropout=0.2)(x)
out = Dense(5,activation='softmax')(x)
model = Model(inputs=Input_words, outputs=[out])
opt = Adam(lr=1e-3, decay=1e-3 / 200)
model.compile(loss = 'categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=opt,metrics = ['accuracy'])
```

If not what would a good solution for this on keras? Can I use [Dropout with noise_shape](https://keras.io/api/layers/regularization_layers/dropout/) to solve my problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can simply test all the possibilities on your own...

we generate one sample of shape (1, n_frame, H, W, n_channel) and visualize the impact of different dropout strategies:

```
inputShape = (100,8,8,1) # frames of 100 grayscale images of size 8x8 
X = np.random.uniform(1,2, (1,)+inputShape).astype('float32') # generate 1 sample

layer = Dropout(0.4, seed=0)
d = layer(X, training=True).numpy()

layer = Dropout(0.4, seed=0, noise_shape=(X.shape[0],1,X.shape[2],X.shape[3],X.shape[4]))
d1d = layer(X, training=True).numpy()

layer = TimeDistributed(SpatialDropout2D(0.4, seed=0))
tsd2d = layer(X, training=True).numpy()

layer = SpatialDropout3D(0.4, seed=0)
# the same as:
# layer = Dropout(0.4, seed=0, noise_shape=(X.shape[0],1,1,1,X.shape[4]))
sd3d = layer(X, training=True).numpy()
```

results from `Dropout`:

```
plt.figure(figsize=(15,12))

for i,f_map in enumerate(d[0]):
    
    if i == 12:
        break
    
    plt.subplot(3,4, i+1)
    plt.imshow(np.squeeze(f_map>0, -1), vmin=0, vmax=1)
    plt.title(f"frame {i}")
```

[image]

results from `Dropout` with `noise_shape`:

```
plt.figure(figsize=(15,12))

for i,f_map in enumerate(d1d[0]):
    
    if i == 12:
        break
    
    plt.subplot(3,4, i+1)
    plt.imshow(np.squeeze(f_map>0, -1), vmin=0, vmax=1)
    plt.title(f"frame {i}")
```

[image]

results from `TimeDistributed` plus `SpatialDropout2D`

```
plt.figure(figsize=(15,12))

for i,f_map in enumerate(tsd2d[0]):
    
    if i == 12:
        break
    
    plt.subplot(3,4, i+1)
    plt.imshow(np.squeeze(f_map>0, -1), vmin=0, vmax=1)
    plt.title(f"frame {i}")
```

[image]

results from `SpatialDropout3D`:

plt.figure(figsize=(15,12))

```
for i,f_map in enumerate(sd3d[0]):
    
    if i == 12:
        break
    
    plt.subplot(3,4, i+1)
    plt.imshow(np.squeeze(f_map>0, -1), vmin=0, vmax=1)
    plt.title(f"frame {i}")
```

[image]

**CONCLUSIONS**

- the simple `Dropout` random drops pixels in each frame without a rule
- `Dropout` with `noise_shape` random drops pixels in each frame always at the same position
- `TimeDistributed` plus `SpatialDropout2D` random drops entire frames randomly
- `SpatialDropout3D` drops all the frames in random channels